# Which version of the .NET Framework should I work with?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, version

How can I decide which version of .net framework suitable for the target ?
I know my target is windows 7 so which version of .net already installed on it ?

> I always after complete my project I made a setup file because I
> would to run it on other PCs.

image:[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVUKV.png).

what is the difference between these versions ?

I work on Winsows-10, visual studio 2013, installer plugin (to made a setup file)